# How does a Biased Interviewer Behave?

Tags: probability, distributions, modeling

Suppose three equally capable candidates are interviewed for a job. One candidate is female, the other two male. The interviewer is biased. What is the probability that the female candidate is successful?

The challenge is to define 'biased' in such a way as to make this question answerable. My first thought was to define it as follows: the interviewer has bias $p$ if, given *two* equally capable candidates, one of which is female and the other male, they choose the female candidate with probability $p$. However it is not clear how to translate this into the situation of three interviewees.

A second approach might be to say that, if $X, Y_1, Y_2$ are the perceived abilities of the candidates (male 1, male 2, female) according to the interviewer, then we might say

$X \sim N(\mu_f, \sigma_f^2)$

$Y_1, Y_2 \sim N(\mu_m, \sigma_m^2)$

Independently. Then the probability of the female candidate being selected is

$P(X>Y_1, X>Y_2)$

However this gets nasty quickly, especially when extending to cases when more than one candidate is to be hired (since we need more than the top order statistic).

Happy to introduce further assumptions if it will make the problem more tractable.

Regards.

(P.S. I posted this on Cross-Validated rather than Mathematics SE, as this seems like more of a question of statistical modelling than of probability theory).

Comment: The underlying question is not sufficiently well framed to have an answer.  What would "probability" of success mean? Should we be considering the qualities of the male competitors as random variables? How about the qualities of the female? How about the judgment of the interviewer?  If you could clarify that meaning, it would help for developing and evaluating possible models.

Comment: All three candidates are equally capable - i.e. their ability is a shared constant, rather than a random variable (though this is just to try to simplify the question - if we can do it with random variables, that would be great). How to model the interviewer's judgement process is the underlying question.

Comment: I thought that might be the thrust of your interest.  Thank you for clarifying it!  Please consider editing your post to emphasize that point.